# Compilation options in ConTeXt document

Tags: compiling, context, context-mkii

Is there a way to supply compilation options from within the document in ConTeXt?

For example the `arrange` option in the following example:
There is a [documented](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Imposition#Caveat:_common_troubles) caveat in imposition mode, where the Table of Contents (TOC) is disabled by default. To enable it, I can run `texexec --arrange untitled.tex`

Comment: You are using texexec, are you asking about MkII or MkIV?

Comment: @TeXnician MkII, added a tag too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Introduction

Below you can find a list of the options which can be passed with the first line of a document. To hide the options from TeX you have to begin the line with a comment character (`%`).

The following example shows a document which is runs only **once** and uses the **dutch** interface.

```
% nofruns=1 interface=nl

\starttekst
...
\stoptekst
```

## List of parameters for `MkII`

## `tex`/`engine`/`program`

- `pdftex` (`tex`, `etex`, `pdftex`, `standard`)
- `aleph` (`aleph`, `omega`)
- `xetex` (`xetex`)
- `petex` (`petex`)

## `output`

- `pdftex` (`pdftex`, `pdf`, `pdftex`, `standard`)
- `dvipdfmx` (`dvipdfmx`, `dvipdfm`, `dpx`, `dpm`)
- `xetex` (`xetex`, `xtx`)
- `dvipdfmx` (`petex`)
- `dvipdfmx` (`aleph`)
- `dvips` (`dvips`, `ps`, `dvi`)
- `dvipsone` (`dvipsone`)
- `acrobat` (`acrobat`, `adobe`, `distiller`)
- `xdv2pdf` (`xdv`, `xdv2pdf`)

## `mode`

- 〈NAME〉

## `ctx`

- 〈FILE〉

## `version`

- 〈DATE〉

## `format`/`interface`

- `plain` (`plain`)
- `cont-en` (`cont-en`, `en`, `english`, `context`, `standard`)
- `cont-nl` (`cont-nl`, `nl`, `dutch`)
- `cont-de` (`cont-de`, `de`, `german`)
- `cont-it` (`cont-it`, `it`, `italian`)
- `cont-fr` (`cont-fr`, `fr`, `french`)
- `cont-cs` (`cont-cs`, `cs`, `cont-cz`, `cz`, `czech`)
- `cont-ro` (`cont-ro`, `ro`, `romanian`)
- `cont-gb` (`cont-gb`, `gb`, `cont-uk`, `uk`, `british`)
- `mptopdf` (`mptopdf`)
- `latex` (`latex`)

## List of parameters for `MkIV`

### `engine`

- `luatex`
- `luajittex`
- `pdftex`
- `xetex`

### `texformat`

- `plain`
- `luatex-plain`

### `interface`

- `en`
- `uk`
- `de`
- `fr`
- `nl`
- `cs`
- `it`
- `ro`
- `pe`

### `nofruns`

- 〈NUMBER〉

### `jiton`

- `yes`
- `no`
- `true`
- `false`

### `jithash`

- 〈TEXT〉

### `directives`

- 〈NAME〉

### `trackers`

- 〈NAME〉

### `experiments`

- 〈NAME〉

### `epub`

- 〈OPTIONS〉